# Relating First Order Theories and Equational Theories

Tags: predicate-logic, model-theory

I am trying to understand the relationship between arbitrary FOL theories and theories that consist of [conditional equations](https://books.google.ie/books?id=85CLRvu5QxUC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22conditional%20equation%22Foundations%20of%20Algebraic%20Specification%20and%20Formal%20Software%20Development%20conditional&source=bl&ots=6YlPW-QH_U&sig=94H9pMkEauRutOj0VXTQGYTDLAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuzeWMv6XXAhVG1xoKHVT-A7AQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22conditional%20equation%22Foundations%20of%20Algebraic%20Specification%20and%20Formal%20Software%20Development%20conditional&f=false) plus [Boolean algebra](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Boolean_algebra) 
 (CEQL+BOOL). For example:

Given the following first order theory for relation R expressed using FOL:

**Theory 1**

[Symmetry]  $\forall x,y : ((R~x~y) \Leftrightarrow (R~y~x))$

[Transitivity] $\forall x,y,z : (((R~x~y) \land ((R~y~z)) \Rightarrow R~x~z)$

[Existence] $\forall x \exists y : (R~x~y)$

**Theory 2** ,below, represents my efforts to transform theory **Theory 1** into a conditional equational theory (CEQL). I permit Boolean Algebra in the language, so we have CEQL+BOOL. Boolean algebra includes the normal logical operators and can be interpreted as propositional logic. CEQL+BOOL admits Skolem functions. All variables are assumed to be universally quantified.  In [conditional equations](https://books.google.ie/books?id=85CLRvu5QxUC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22conditional%20equation%22Foundations%20of%20Algebraic%20Specification%20and%20Formal%20Software%20Development%20conditional&source=bl&ots=6YlPW-QH_U&sig=94H9pMkEauRutOj0VXTQGYTDLAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuzeWMv6XXAhVG1xoKHVT-A7AQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22conditional%20equation%22Foundations%20of%20Algebraic%20Specification%20and%20Formal%20Software%20Development%20conditional&f=false), variables in the conditions $(t_1 = t'_1 \land  \dots \land t_n = t'_n)$ that do not appear in the consequent $(t_0 = t'_0)$ can be seen as existentially quantified in a FOL context. For example:

$\forall x,y : t \bullet ((x \times y = 1) \Rightarrow (x \times x^{-1} = 1))$

is equivalent to the formula

$\forall x : t \bullet ((\exists y : t \bullet (x \times y = 1)) \Rightarrow (x \times x^{-1}=1))$

in ordinary first-order logic.

**Theory 2** expressed in CEQL+BOOL

[Symmetry] $(R~x~y) = (R~y~x)$

[Transitivity] $((R~x~y) = \top) \land ((R~y~z) = \top)) \Rightarrow (R~x~z = \top$)

[Existence] $(R~x~skolem(x)) = \top$

**Theorem 1** 
Using **Theory 2** show that R is reflexive: $\vdash (\forall x (R~x~x))$

**Proof** of **Theorem 1** using CEQL+BOOL

\begin{align*}
     &~~~~\{\text{Transitivity Axiom\}} \\
    &(1)~~~~((R~x~y) = \top) \land ((R~y~z) = \top) \Rightarrow (R~z~x = \top)\\
    & \text{ \{Substitution, z = x \}} \\
    &(2)~~~~((R~x~y) = \top) \land ((R~y~x)  = \top) \Rightarrow (R~x~x = \top)\\
    &= \text{\{Symmetry Axiom at term (2.2.1)\}} \\
    &(4)~~~~((R~x~y) = \top) \land ((R~x~y)  = \top) \Rightarrow (R~x~x = \top)\\
    &= \text{\{Substitution, y = skolem(x) \}}\\   
    &(5)~~~~((R~x~skolem(x)) = \top) \land ((R~x~skolem(x))  = \top) \Rightarrow (R~x~x = \top)\\
    &= \text{\{Existance axiom \}} \\
    &(6)~~~~(\top \land \top)\Rightarrow (R~x~x = \top)\\
    &= \text{\{ Boolean Algebra: Idempotency of $\land$\}}\\
    &(7)~~~~\top \Rightarrow (R~x~x = \top)\\
    &= \text{\{Boolean Algebra: Left identity of $\Rightarrow$\}}\\
    &(8)~~~~(R~x~x = \top)
  \end{align*}

Are the transform and proof reasonable?

This question uses same theorem proved in [Prove reflexivity using Fitch software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492570/prove-reflexivity-using-fitch-software)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation, but I'd say the transform and proof are both 'reasonable', yes.

Comment: Please copy the stuff from the links into the body of the question.

Comment: When I try to embed the images the systems says that I need at least 10 credits to post images. I will try to use Latex.

Comment: I have added Latex and further details of conditional equations